# java.lang.ClassCastException: geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent thrown when comparing two numbers as strings

Tags: groovy

I need to compare number of values against one parent within method:

```
def checkFilterAppliedByPriceDescending() {

    firstPriceValue.text().replace(/\D*/, "")

    allPrices.each() {
        if (it.text().replace(/\D*/, "") > firsPriceValue) {
            throw new Exception("Wrong price found: " + it)
        }
    }
}
```

I use with regex to eliminate all non-digits so it would look like `99999` for example. However, when I run the test I get following error:

```
checkFilterAppliedByPriceDescending()
|
java.lang.ClassCastException: geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String
    at SearchPageFiltersTest.Can navigate to AutoHero Search Page(RouterTest.groovy:21)

    Caused by:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String
```

Could you please help me understanding what's wrong with the method and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be aware that

```
firstPriceValue.text().replace(/\D*/, "")
```

does not mutate `firstPriceValue`. Method `text()` returns a String representation and Strings are immutable, so calling `replace()` on a String returns a new one and does not mutate the String you called the method on. To fix it you have to capture the result from the above method and assign it to a variable, for instance:

```
def price = firstPriceValue.text().replace(/\D*/, "")
```

Another thing is that comparing Strings with `>` won't work as you expect. Take a look at this example from Groovy shell:

```
groovy:000> '9999' > '10000'
===> true
```

To avoid such problems you would have to cast number represented as String to a numeric value, `BigDecimal` for instance:

```
groovy:000> ('9999' as BigDecimal) > ('10000' as BigDecimal)
===> false
```

And lastly, you can use collection's `every()` method to make sure that all prices match specific predicate. Something like this:

```
def price = firstPriceValue.text().replace(/\D*/, "") as BigDecimal

assert allPrices.every { 
    def currentPrice = it.text().replace(/\D*/, "") as BigDecimal
    return currentPrice > price 
}
```

`allPrices.every()` will return `true` if all prices match given predicate and `false` otherwise.